# How to partially update a document in Cosmos DB NodeJS client without index

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to update a document in Cosmos DB using the Node Cosmos DB Client. The thing is that I can't count on the index to update it. Reading the docs I found this [Conditional Patch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/patch-a-document#conditional-patch-operation) but the only example doesn't have an array.

Basically I need to update an item inside of an array which I don't know the index. I need to filter by on of its properties

Example: Below I need to update the "Capacity" on the item with "email = user1@email.com" from "Has Capacity" to "No Capacity" (without use the index)

```
{
  "id": "9999",
  "DocType": "Settings",
  "ShowPrice": true,
  "Sourcing": [
    {
      "Function": "ABC",
      "Capability": "DEF",
      "Capacity": "Has Capacity",
      "Contact": "user1@email.com",
      "DateUpdated": "2022-05-24T20:21:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "Function": "GHI",
      "Capability": "FDG",
      "Capacity": "No Capacity",
      "Contact": "user2@email.com",
      "DateUpdated": "2022-09-26T20:21:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my current code

```
return await this.container.item(id, partitionKeyValue).patch({
  condition: 'FROM c IN t.Sourcing WHERE c.Contact = "user1@email.com"', 
  operations: [
    {
      op: "replace",
      path: "/Sourcing",
      value: "No Capacity",
    },
  ],
});
```

Can anyone help on that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific use case, to patch existing objects which lies in a path that comprises of arrays, then the index must be known. So it’s not possible to achieve a patch on the array without knowing the index and currently, we don’t have any plans to support this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess you replied to this same question on the MS forum haha.

I changed the logic to be able to use index